# Custom Word text box linked to pc, not document

Tags: microsoft-word

Good morning

Is there a workaround to my problem?

I have a Word document in which I added a custom text box, so my colleagues can just add that specific text box and its position and contents are automatically correct.

However, it works on my computer, but not on others, because Word is saving the custom building block on the pc, not the document. Saving the file as a template (*.dotx) did not solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend storing the building block in a template, but think you may need to make that template in a different way that you did previously. I am using Word 2010; the concept is likely similar for your version.

1. Make a new template based not based off of the normal template: `File > New > select Blank Document > click Create button`. Save the file.
2. Copy and paste your building block material into the document or
   recreate it.
3. Highlight the block material and create the block. `Insert tab >
   Quick Parts > Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery.`
4. Make sure to assign the block to the template by choosing the
   template in the "Save in" field.

[image: Saving custom block]

[image: Building Block List]

5. Save the file and you should be ready to share.

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not solve the issue. The text box is still not visible on someone else's pc. Document can be downloaded via http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69903357969099561589

Comment: I see your building block just fine. I downloaded the template, created a new document in Word, then applied the template—the building block was there. It has "Punten-verdeling" and a /5 in a text box on the left hand side. Because this building block is categorized to show in the text box gallery, I would make sure your user knows to access it from the text box dropdown and not the quick parts dropdown.

Comment: My colleagues tested this on Mac computers. It's indeed working as intended in Windows. Thank you,!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, I would save a document containing the text box (1 page?) as its own file and have your colleagues insert this file as needed into their docs (or rename and use as a new stand-alone file). I am frankly mystified that the text box does not appear to be saving with your doc. Please note that if there is no text in the box, the box will not be visible when you view the doc, of course, unless you click on it or unless you have enhanced the box with an outline.